# How to fill inputs when editing an article in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a list of articles.
[image]

After I press Edit, I am redirected to another page containing in the url the id of the article that wants to be edited.

```
<a href="edit_article/{{article.0}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="btnEditArticle">Edit</a>
```

This is where I am redirected:
[image]
And I want the inputs to be filled with the title and the body text of the respective article.

This is my backend function:

```
@app.route('/edit_article/<string:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_article(id):
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    result = cursor.execute("SELECT * from articles where id=%s", [id])
    data = cursor.fetchone()

    if result < 0:
        flash("Article does not exist!")

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return render_template("edit_article.html", data=data)
```

How can I use `data` to fill those inputs? Please help. Thank you.

I will put also the `edit_article.html`

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bucket List App</h1>
        <form class="form-addArticle">
        <label for="inputTitle" class="sr-only">Title</label>
        <input type="name" name="inputTitle" id="inputTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputBody" class="sr-only">Body</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputBody" id="inputBody" class="form-control" placeholder="Body" required autofocus>

        <button id="btnEditArticle" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Update article</button>
      </form>
          <p class="text-center" style="color:red" id="message"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just need to add `value="{{ ... }}"` to your inputs:

```
<input type="name" value="{{ data[0] }}" name="inputTitle" id="inputTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
<input type="text" value="{{ data[1] }}" name="inputBody" id="inputBody" class="form-control" placeholder="Body" required autofocus>
```

But it's recommended to name the values:

```
name, text = cursor.fetchone()
return render_template("edit_article.html", name=name, text=text)
```

and then

```
<input type="name" value="{{ name }}" name="inputTitle" id="inputTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
<input type="text" value="{{ text }}" name="inputBody" id="inputBody" class="form-control" placeholder="Body" required autofocus>
```

But I'd personally recommend WTForms module instead of rendering forms manually - it can for example help to validate your inputs properly.